# How do I account for hardward delay in a playrec code in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio-recording

I would like to add a delay to the playrec code that I am troubleshooting.

For context, I have been running a playrec script that will play a chirp and record the resulting sound. It runs properly and does not return any errors, but the resulting phase plot does not look accurate. It has been narrowed down to a delay problem; there may be an unaccounted-for delay between playing the audio and recording it, but I am not sure how to integrate delay when using playrec.

Below is a part of the script that I have been working on to try and resolve this.

```
    for n = 1: repetitions
        playrec('playrec',db2mag(-30)*buffer(driver,:)',3,length(buffer(1,:))+Delay,3);

    end
    blockcompletion = playrec('block',(repetitions * m)-1); % block until last page
    for n = 0: (repetitions - 1)
        pagesPerCalib = repetitions;
        playrecpage = n + (pagesPerCalib * (m-1));
        
        %Start playing from the buffer:
        recording_buffer(n+1,:)=playrec('getRec',playrecpage)';
    end
    playrec('delPage');
    Vin(m, :, :) = recording_buffer( (ThrowAwayTrials + 1):end, (Delay+1):end);
```

I have lengthened the recording buffer and added the delay to the recording line. As for the length of the delay itself, I tried delaying the recording by the cross-correlation between the 'play' buffer and the 'recording' buffer (~90 samples), which did not improve the phase curve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there is anything else that I can provide to make things clearer.

Thank you,
Andrew

Comment: Where is the phase curve? You could not by any chance make the code a self-contained example code? See [example]?